# axios post response is undefined for react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I have used axios post to fetch the data in react-native but response is undefined. Sometimes it cant catch the error but it can be caused by my backend code.

I tried http and https but this didn't work or it doesnt working with or without header. Is there anyone to find the mistake on my code?

```
 axios
      .post(
        "http://192.168.1.34:3000/auth/",
        {
          email: email,
          password: password
        },
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(email);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("loginAction:", error);
      });
```

Comment: what do you expect from the backend?

Comment: just want to return token of user with specified email and password. Postman is totally works.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interceptor to return the response and sometimes you need to use http://10.0.2.2 instead of localhost

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error.response);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing I'd do is check CORS for your POST request.

Its often an overlooked issue and relatively easy to solve. Postman is good about setting correct headers and options. If it still doesn't work I would go through Postmans set up one by one and mimic the POST there..